# title in page.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming

I find out `title` is not exists in `page.html.twig`, and there is a file `page-title.html.twig` to theme title, then in block section we should use block title. ( ** I don't want use this strange structure for title,really I  didn't find out why Drupal do this  !!!).

any way 
I want to provide it by myself, maybe `hook_preprocess_page` is solution,any body know how can I add `title` variable to page variables ?

Comment: You can find the reasons why this was done here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2568563 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2476947

Comment: @4k4 thanks. but if I don't want use any region and block system then ? I think  beside block title, title variable have to exists in page templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution for adding `title` to page templates.
in `yourthemename.theme` add

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if(isset($vars['node'])) {
        $vars['title'] = $vars['node']->title->value;
    }
    else{
       $vars['title'] =$vars['page']['#title'];
    }
 }
```

then `title` exist in page templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with:

```
{% if node.label %}
  {{ node.label }}
{% else %}
  {{ page['#title'] }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it's about page title, not just node title ;-)

Comment: True, edited answer.

Comment: I prefer the previous answer. because it handled in PHP side and FrontEnd developer shouldn't care about the logic.